# Save data in local storage before calling a component Header

Tags: angular

I am beginner in angular 4 I looked in different places but I did not find a solution.
Indeed my problem is that: I would like to record the id of my user logged in the local storage for to use in the second component.
Current Scenario:

1) user loggIn

2) redirect to page

3) error userId not found

How to store data in local storage before calling ngInit

[image: screenshot]

[image]

[image]ack.imgur.com/CVWfm.png

[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes i have this error:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 400 OK for URL: http://localhost:8080/countNotification/null
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at eval (zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)

Comment: but when I refresh the page all it works

Comment: Is your user id actually stored in the local storage?

Comment: yes of course all information is stored same id
but I think the call LocalStorage.getItem ('') and ngOnit is at the same time

Comment: I dont understant your question. Could you be more specific?

Comment: No ngOnInt method invokes right after ther constructor. Try debugging the code in the constructor.

Comment: @Juan 
when the user connects it is written to a page of my template,
in my header I use a method to calculate the notification number for the connected UI

but i can not get the id user back only when i refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

If I understant your question, you have one component (loginComponent) where the user makes the loggin. If the loggin is succesfull you want to store in the localStorage the user id and then retrieve this id in a second component (secondComponent). You can do it like this:

In loginComponent you create a login method:

```
login(credentials) {
    let correctUserAndPass: boolean = //Make your verification

    if (correctUserAndPass) {
        localStorage.setItem('userId', credentials["user"]);
        this.router.navigate(['/secondComponent']);
    } else {
        // Credentials invalid
    }
```

In your secondComponent:

```
ngOnInit() {
     if (!localStorage.getItem('userId')) {
         this.router.navigate(['/loginComponent'] // The userId is not stored in localStorage
     } else {
         userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

it always stays in the login page